# What is hadoop namenode command used for

Tags: hadoop

What is the use of `hadoop namenode` command?
What is the difference between `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop-deamon.sh start namenode`?
I formatted namenode and then executed hadoop namenode
It throwed an error

> ERROR namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 2: SIGINT

What does that mean and what is the use of`hadoop namenode` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hadoop` command accepts any of these arguments `namenode`|`datanode`|`secondarynamenode`|`journalnode`|`zkfc`|`balancer` and runs the corresponding daemon process.

```
hadoop namenode
```

when executed without any additional arguments will run the `Namenode` daemon.

```
hadoop-daemon.sh
```

script is only a wrapper for `hadoop` and `hdfs` command. It accepts the same set of daemon names arguments to `start`/`stop` the process when invoked. Also, It takes care of starting the process in the background.

> ERROR namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 2: SIGINT

`SIGINT 2` is thrown when the execution of a command is interrupted (KeyBoardInterrupt). When `hadoop namenode` is executed, the command blocks the terminal and any interruptions (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> ) in this terminal would end the process with this error message.

Comment: What is the reason of blocking the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop NameNode contains the metadata of the files which are present in HDFS. This meta data is present in serialized form inside a single file(fsimage). The NameNode also contains an edits file that has a log of all the changes made to the file system. The fsimage file is kept both ondisk and in-memory. All changes to file system is reflected in-memory and periodically transferred to disk.
Details on how to fetch fsimage and edits file is given here HDFS File System Metadata Backup.

NameNode is the [single point of failure](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module7.html) in a Hadoop cluster. Though the loss of any other machine (intermittently or permanently) does not result in data loss because of data replication, NameNode loss results in cluster unavailability. The permanent loss of NameNode data would render the cluster's HDFS inoperable.
Therefore, another step should be taken in this configuration to back up the NameNode metadata to start it again.

References: Check [this blog post](http://vijayjt.blogspot.in/2013/02/hdfs-file-system-metadata-backup.html) from Vijay. I would suggest you to refer [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#NameNode+and+DataNodes) as well.